# Getting a List of Symbols Used by My VC++ Code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debug-symbols, dia-sdk, browse-information

I am building a tool that process my VC++ source codes.  For this, I need to obtain a list of symbols including local variable names and their types used by my codes.  I know Visual C++ 2010 already provides a .bsc file that allows the object browser to locate symbols quickly.  But this is an interactive tool.  I need to obtain a list of the symbols in a file.  Is there any tools allowing us to programmatically obtain the list of symbols used in our own VC++ source codes?

I tried the Debug Interface Access SDK provided by Microsoft.  It allows us to read the .pdb file for the names of the local variables used.  But I also want to obtain the exact type names used in my source codes. e.g.

```
MYTYPE dwordVar;
```

DIA SDK allows us to obtain the string "dwordVar" which is the name of a local variable.  But it cannot tell its type name is "MYTYPE".  It can only tell us what MYTYPE really represents (like unsigned long). But not the symbol "MYTYPE".

If Visual C++ isnt offering this feature, is there any third party tools supporting this feature?

Comment: IDiaSymbol has a *lot* of properties.  Be sure to distinguish get_type from get_baseType.  Posting a snippet would be wise.

Comment: @HansPassant: Only [these properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8ae4k32.aspx) are valid for Data symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Experimenting with this program:

```
typedef unsigned long MYTYPE;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    MYTYPE test = 99LU;
}
```

both DIA SDK and DbgHelp return 16 (`SymTagBaseType`) for the symtype of the type symbol for `test`. It would be nice if the type symbol were a Typedef symbol (17/`SymTagTypedef`), but it might be that the PDB itself does not record whether the source file used a `typedef` or type name in declaring the type of the local variable.

One possible work-around is to enumerate the `SymTagTypedef` children of the global scope symbol, building a `std::multimap` from type IDs of the types to the `typedef` names. Then, for each local variable, if the multimap contains entries for the Data symbol's type ID (obtained via [`IDiaSymbol::get_typeId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xks45awc.aspx)), use the [`IDiaSession::findLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7wkd78s.aspx) method to figure out the line(s) on which the Data symbol is declared and search those lines for any of the `typedef` name strings, possibly performing preprocessing before searching.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to locate, using IDiaSession::findLines or the like, which lines in the source code are containing variable declaration? I've done some tests and it seems that a local variable declaration line will not even be counted as a source code line in the ::findLines call.

Comment: @JavaMan: Sorry for the delay. I tried both DIA SDK and DbgHelp and neither returns line information for a local variable declaration, or even a global variable declaration. The best that I could get were the line number(s) of the [lexical parent symbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/202d5966.aspx), which for the case of a local variable declaration is the Function symbol. Pretty frustrating...